# The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: c#, base64

Facing issue for `FromBase64String` method.

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Tried replacing `-` to `+`

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(id);
id = "59216167-f9c0-4b1b-b1db-1babd1209f10@ABC"
```

Expected result is string should be converted to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer array.

Comment: Tried converting '-' character to '+' character still it's not working

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Yes, that is a non valid base64 string. What would you expect we do?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a Base64 encoded string. It's a Guid. You can read it into a byte array like this

```
var bytearray = new Guid("59216167-f9c0-4b1b-b1db-1babd1209f10").ToByteArray();
```

Comment: TBH, it's not even a valid `Guid`. The runtime error should be `Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes`. Specifically in the OP original post, the actual problem of that *Guid* is the last 4 characters; `@ABC`, removing them will succeed. So, I would recommend updating your post to include that it's not even a valid *Guid*...

Answer (score 2):

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string

The exact reason you are getting this type of error is because **it's not a valid Base64 string**, instead as already mentioned, it's a `Guid`; and **not a valid Guid at that**.

First you can check if you even have a valid `Base64` string by trying to convert it.

```
public static bool StringIsBase64(string myString)
{
   Span<byte> buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[myString.Length]);
   return Convert.TryFromBase64String(myString, buffer , out int bytesParsed);
}
```

Now if you call this function and it succeeds, then we would assume you do have a valid `Base64` string, otherwise a conversion error would occur.

Your call can now look like this:

```
 string id = "59216167-f9c0-4b1b-b1db-1babd1209f10@ABC";
 var bytes;
 if (StringIsBase64(id))
 {
    bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(id);
 }
```

Something else I would like to address that none of the other answers addressed, is the input **is not valid for even a Guid**. A [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.8) is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) and that string isn't valid.

You actually would receive the error:

> Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

The characters `@ABC` at the end of the string are causing this, if these are removed then we have an actual valid `Guid`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this will Help

```
    using System;
    public class Program{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Guid gg = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine(gg);
        string ss = Encode(gg);
        Console.WriteLine(ss);
        Console.WriteLine(Decode(ss));
    }
    public static string Encode(Guid guid)
    {
        string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(guid.ToByteArray());
        encoded = encoded.Replace("/", "_").Replace("+", "-");
        return encoded.Substring(0, 22);
    }

    public static Guid Decode(string value)
    {
        value = value.Replace("_", "/").Replace("-", "+");
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value + "==");
        return new Guid(buffer);
    }




}
```